# Good async/await alternate to Object.keys forEach?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to perform a few tasks in a function (fetch a web-page, and perform some calculations and such), however my list of websites to visit is in an key-value paired object.

I need to find some async/await compatible alternate to `forEach` which will work on `Object.keys()`.

Since `Object.keys(sites).forEach(function(key, index) { ... }` doesn't seem to allow async calls within it, what's the best alternative?

The loop essentially fetches multiple sites, validates the JSON data, and adds it to a an array if valid.

It then later loops over the new array via a standard for and compares the results, before returning either boolean `true` or `false`.

Comment: Use `for ... of`

Comment: @MarkMeyer do you have an example of this syntax with Object.keys()? Sorry I'm quite new to JS

Comment: ```for ... of``` gives me: ```Servers is not iterable```. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable suggests using Object.keys() but I cannot for this as it isn't async.